# Integration of an integral part of x?

Tags: integration, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If $ f(x)={\left\lfloor x^2\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor ^2}$,where ${\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor }$ denotes the greatest integer $\le x$ then $\int_1^2 f(x)dx?$ 
please give some hint.
thank you.

Comment: Break the interval into regions where $1<x^2<2$, $2<x^2<3$ and $3<x^2<4$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the interval $(1,2)$ you have $[x] = 1$. On the interval $(1,\sqrt2)$ you have $[x^2] = 1$ and on the interval $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ you have $[x^2] = 3$ and on the interval $(\sqrt{3}, 4)$ you have $[x^2] = 3$. So you can break on the integral into:
$$\begin{align}
\int_1^2 f(x) \; dx &= \int_1^\sqrt{2} f(x)\; dx + \int_\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{3} f(x)\; dx + \int_\sqrt{3}^2 f(x)\; dx\\
&= \int_1^\sqrt{2} 1 - 1 \; dx + \int_\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{3} 2-1\; dx + \int_\sqrt{3}^2 3- 1\; dx
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Our resident serial downvoter seems to be visiting us, @Thomas...+1 to balance and for a nice effort to answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio and Thomas - never mind this downvote. I just notice that my reputation has decreased by 1, and when I checked what happened I saw this answer downvoted by myself (by no means intentionally). Have no idea, how it happened, but I apologize anyway :) now I shall take a look on all my previous downvotes. Btw, +1 for the answer

Comment: @Ilya: No problem. It's all good. :)

Comment: thank you @thomas.i think u wrote values reverse in the integral.

Comment: @user59489: I sure did. Thanks.

Comment: So in fact it was the *unconscious* downvoter...? :)